# Given a rational matrix $Q$, can we generate $\langle Q^{i}(v)\mid i\in\mathbb Z,v\in\mathbb Z^{2}\rangle$ using only non-negative powers of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, number-theory

Let $Q $ be a matrix in  $ \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q}) $.   Consider the group $ \langle Q^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb Z, v \in 
\mathbb Z^{2}  \rangle$ under vector addition. I would like to know if this group can be generated using only the non-negative power of a matrix, i.e.

**Question**: does there exists a matrix $P \in \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})$  , such that

$$  \langle Q^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb Z, v \in \mathbb  Z^{2}  \rangle = \langle P^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb N, v \in \mathbb  Z^{2}  \rangle . 
$$

I can show that such $P$ exists when there exists $n \in \mathbb  Z$, such that $Q^n$ has the following form

- Integer matrix (We can take $Q$ to be $P^{-1}$);
- upper triangular matrix (hence diagonal matrix).

However, for a general matrix $Q$, it is quite difficult to compute  $\langle Q^{i}(v) \mid i \in \mathbb Z, v \in \mathbb  Z^{2}  \rangle$ by hand. Another difficulty is that we can't put a rational matrix in echelon form.

I feel the Cayley-Hamilton theorem might be useful, because it tells us that, for $i\in \mathbb N$, $Q^{i}$ can be written as linear combinations of $Q$ and $I$ with rational coefficients, similarly, $Q^{-i}$ can be written as linear combinations of $Q^{-1}$ and $I$ with rational coefficients. It is not obvious if this would help because of the fact that the coefficient might be non-integer.

Any ideas/references would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide context.

Comment: What do you mean by group? Under addition?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q} ^2$

Comment: Note $Q^i$ can be written as $a_iQ+b_iI,$ where $a_i,b_i$ are rational numbers which have a recurrence in terms of $\operatorname{tr}Q$ and $\det Q.$

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndrews, Do you know if the formulae can be written explicitly? and does it hold when $i$ is a negative integer?

Comment: The recurrence can go backwards. $(a_0,b_0)=(0,1).$ Then $a_{i+1}=b_i+a_i\operatorname{tr} Q, b_{i+1}=-a_i\det Q.$ If the determinant and trace are integers, you can write this group as simply $\langle Q^iv\mid i=0,1\rangle,$ and $P=Q$ works.

Comment: Oh yes, this follows from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem!

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong you need the determinant $\pm 1$ and the trace an integer for $P=Q$ to work - the negative $i$ gives rational $a_i,b_i$ otherwise.

Comment: The word "generate" would be more appropriate and more precise than "describe".

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454636/given-a-rational-matrix-q-can-we-generate-langle-qiv-mid-i-in-mathbb-z